Command Line argument in PLPGSQL declaration
I am running this script which takes two command line arguments and it gives me error about syntax being wrong.
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO variables values (:'employee_serial');
                                      ^
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO variables values (:'ticket_id');
                                      ^

Understanding that the command line arguments cannot be accepted same as normal I have made changes to first put the values in a temporary table in and then accessing them in the DECLARATION.
Here's my code:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE variables (var TEXT);
INSERT INTO variables values (:'employee_serial');
INSERT INTO variables values (:'ticket_id');


DO $$
DECLARE
  employee_id_var INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT t.employee_id INTO employee_id_var
  FROM some_table t
  WHERE t.employee_serial = (SELECT var from variables LIMIT (0,1));

  UPDATE tickets
  SET employee_id = employee_id_var
  WHERE ticket_id = (SELECT var from variables LIMIT (1,1));
END $$;

The command I'm using to run the script is:
postgres=# \i <path_to_file>/update_assets.sql -v employee_serial='1468800007' -v ticket_id='397785'

Can anyone please point out the mistakes in this?

Using = makes your subqueries scalar, that is, you ger an error if they return more than a single row. Use IN instead.
